# Security concerns when importing class libraries

Tags: java, security, jvm

When importing class libraries in Java if you use a wildcard (i.e. java.util.*) does this create security concerns since there are probably a bunch of libraries that are invoked that are not going to be used? Also will this slow down your program during execution? If not why don't we just always import every class?

Comment: For starter. Java makes it illegal to use java. as a custom package name or add your own classes to any java namespace (sigh)

Answer (score 1):

1. Libraries aren't "invoked". They're simply imported so the compiler
   knows which class you're referring to without using the fully
   qualified name
2. It's a directive for the compiler, it has nothing to do with runtime
   performance
3. If you imported every package, it would be useless, and classes with
   same names would then require you to use the FQN to determine which
   one you're referring to

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense.